# How can I keep a file in memory during editing?

Tags: bash, vim, gnupg

Short version : echo "testing" | vim - | grep "good"

This doesn't work as vim won't output to a pipe. It says : "Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal". Any way to do this? Cross-editor support would be nice too.

I've tried named pipes, but vim won't open them.

Long version : echo $passw | gpg -q -d --passphrase-fd 0 $filename | vim - | "somehow gpg encrypt it using $passw and store it back in $filename".

I'm trying to edit a gpg encrypted file but would like to not have the decrypted file on disk at any time.

The full script is here : https://github.com/ptarjan/viencrypt

Comment: Performing pathname expansion and wordsplitting on your passphrase sounds like a really bad idea.  Learn to quote: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/Quoting -- Quote EVERY parameter expansion ("$passw", "$filename", ..)

Comment: @lhunath, @Paul Tarjan: Or just migrate to `zsh`. It by default is not going to perform neither pathname expansion nor word splitting when you use `command $var`: here it is complete equivalent of `command "$var"` unless you’ve set some weird (for a zsh user) options.

Comment: @Paul, is the script still available? Link is broken...

Comment: @Simon updated the link, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: sh ~/viencrypt.sh mypasswords.gpg # opens file in vim & worked just fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just have vim encrypt it for you.

Before you save the file in vim, filter the content through your gpg encrypter:

```
    :{range}![!]{filter} [!][arg]               *:range!*
          Filter {range} lines through the external program
          {filter}.  Vim replaces the optional bangs with the
          latest given command and appends the optional [arg].
          Vim saves the output of the filter command in a
          temporary file and then reads the file into the
          buffer.  Vim uses the 'shellredir' option to redirect
          the filter output to the temporary file.
          However, if the 'shelltemp' option is off then pipes
          are used when possible (on Unix).
          When the 'R' flag is included in 'cpoptions' marks in
          the filtered lines are deleted, unless the
          |:keepmarks| command is used.  Example: >
            :keepmarks '<,'>!sort
    <            
          When the number of lines after filtering is less than
          before, marks in the missing lines are deleted anyway.
        w
```

So, if you want to filter it through gpg (I'm guessing at the flags here):

```
:%!gpg -q -d -p $password
:w $filename
```

You'll need to export the `$password` and `$filename` environment variables so
vim has access to them if you want to use them within vim.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it could work.

I'm trying to streamline my process of password management. I currently do 

    gpg passwords.gpg
    vim passwords
    gpg -c passwords
    rm passwords

which takes in 3 passwords and stores the file on disk. I was hoping to avoid that. Would you "commands in vim" method work any better?

Comment: Sure, you could do `vim passwords.gpg`, then within vim do `:%!gpg -` to decrypt your file, make your edits, and then do `:%!gpg -e` to re-encrypt it, and then save with `:w`.  You could even set up autocmds to automatically decrypt .gpg files on open and redecrypt on write (which would keep you from accidentally writing the undecrypted version to disk)

Comment: that should be -d to decrypt, sorry.

Comment: and that should be "reencrypt on write"

Comment: I think the autocmds would be `au BufReadPre *.gpg %!gpg -d` and `au BufWritePre *.gpg %!gpg -e`, but I haven't tested them.  Actually, defining BufReadCmd and BufWriteCmd might be better (but a little more involved)

Comment: Thorough answer, thank you. I'm using passphrase symmetric encryption so that I can use this password file anywhere and don't need a gpg private key in that location. I still have to type my password 3 times using your first method and sadly it isn't seemless to the user. The autocmds look interesting, can those go somewhere on the `vim` command line?

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that by default Vim will create a swap file on disk. Start vim with the following command to avoid it:

```
vim "+set noswapfile"
```

Comment: Wonderful. Added that to the script.

Answer (score 3):

You could mount a tmpfs filesystem (which stores data in memory) somewhere and do your work there.

EDIT (!): Sorry, make that ramfs. The difference is tmpfs can be paged out to swap space, which you don't want. Alternatively, you could turn off all swap devices (with swapoff) and use tmpfs.

Comment: Interesting. Is this available in userspace?

mount -t ramfs ramfs /tmp/ramfs/
mount: only root can do that

If the user could do it, that would be preferable as I want this method to work on boxes where I'm not root.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the [gnupg](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3645) plugin for Vim instead of reinventing the wheel. :) Of course, I'm a little biased since I'm the current maintainer of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct: Vim won't output to a pipe.  Vim doesn't take its input and output it to a pipe, rather it outputs it into an editor window where you can edit it.  You can't continue the pipe sequence after vim.  So try:

echo $passw | gpg -q -d --passphrase-fd 0 $filename | vim -

Or don't use vim at all.

If you want to edit the file before passing back to gpg you'll have to do this in a two step process.

Comment: I currently do this, but the file is on disk. If my box reboots, and someone takes the drive they can have all my passwords. Unlikely, but still not ideal. 

The script that does it is http://github.com/ptarjan/gpg-encrypt/tree/master

Comment: You could do a "shred" on the file afterwords to rewrite it with 0's.

Comment: Ok, added shred option. Now the only race is that JUST after I save it but before I remove it. Race conditions are bad, but this one doesn't have user-input in the loop.

Comment: From the shred manual page "CAUTION: Note that shred relies on a very important assumption: that the file system overwrites data in place." Almost all of my filesystems are journaled. Is there any reason to do `shred` then?

Comment: Good catch... I forgot about that.  Looks like my "down and dirty" way might not work and you may have to use one of the other much more suffisticated methods that others have responded with.

I think shred might still work most of the time on journaled FS, but just isn't gaurenteed to work in certain special situations.  Especially, perhaps, as the disk starts getting full... but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: Not that it will do you any good, but if you are curious like I am see the question I just posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913282/shred-doesnt-work-on-journaled-fs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%p` command to print the file being edited to the standard output.

In this example, Vim reads its standard input and sends it to the standard output:

```
$ (echo one; echo two; echo three; echo four) | \
  vim - -nes -u NONE  -c ':%p' -c ':q!' | \
  tail -n +2 | \
  grep t
two
three
```

Notes:

- `vim -`: read from standard input
- `-n`: don't create swapfile, use memory only
- `-e`: start in ex mode
- `-s`: silent or batch mode
- `-u NONE`: don't read the `.vimrc` (If you want your `.vimrc` to be read, skip this option. But different people have different `.vimrc`-s, so if you don't write `-u NONE`, your code may not work for a different person or even for you if you change your `.vimrc`.)
- `-c <something>`: run something as a command
- `-c ':%p'`: print the content of the buffer to the standard output
- `-c 'q!'`: quit without saving
- `tail -n +2`: throw the first line of the Vim output away (that is the line '`Vim: Reading from stdin...`')

In the following example, Vim does actually something useful: it deletes the first column of the standard input.

```
$ (echo one; echo two; echo three; echo four) | \
  vim - -nes -u NONE  -c ':exec "normal G\<c-v>ggx"' -c ':%p' -c ':q!' | \
  tail -n +2
ne
wo
hree
our
```

Notes:

- `:exec`: execute the following command (command-line command, not normal mode command)
- `normal`: a command-line command that executes the given normal mode commands
- `G`: go to the last line of the file
- `\<c-v>`: start block selection
- `gg`: go to the first line
- `x`: delete the selected characters

EDIT:

> Can I tell vim issue the ":%p" right after I ":wq" from the interactive session?

You can tell Vim things like "run command X before exiting", using e.g. the
VimLeave autocommand (see `:help autocommand`, `:help VimLeave`):

```
$ (echo "line 1"; echo "line 2") | \
  vim - -nes -u NONE -c ':autocmd VimLeave * :%p'
Vim: Reading from stdin...
:q!        # you type :q!
line 1
line 2
```

The problem is with the ":%p" command. If you use the "-e" argument, you won't
get the visual editor. If you don't use "-e", Vim won't print the result of
":%p" to the standard output but to the terminal.

I will make a different suggestion in another post.

Comment: Thanks! This is getting really close. I didn't mention above that I would like an interactive vim session as well. Scripting an edit to my password file is quite difficult and I don't want my edit showing up in the process listing anyways. Can I tell vim issue the ":%p" right after I ":wq" from the interactive session?

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the original problem (as far as I see it):

`secret.txt` contains the encrypted text.

`./encode.sh` is the symmetric encoder script.

The following command will read the text from secret.txt, decode, make it
editable in Vim, encode, and write it back to secret.txt:

```
$ cp secret.txt | \
  ./encode.sh | \
  vim - -n -u NONE \
      -c ':autocmd VimLeave * :exec "%!./encode.sh" | write! tmp'; \
  mv tmp secret.txt
```

Notes:

- `:autocmd VimLeave * <command>`: perform `<command>` before leaving Vim on any file
- `:exec "%!./encode.sh" | write! secret.txt`: run `./encode.sh` on the whole
  content of the buffer as a filter, then write the buffer into `secret.txt`
- "As a filter" means that the content of the buffer will be fed into
  `./encode.sh`. The content of the buffer will be replaced with the standard
  output of `./encode.sh` after it finished its execution.

But I have to say, this solution is ugly. I would recommend [the same as rampion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908457/how-can-i-keep-a-file-in-memory-during-editing/908703#908703): have a look at the autocommands mentioned (`:help autocommand`) and try to do the whole edit process within Vim.

Finally a side note: Vim has its own encryption command which does exactly what you described on your [project web page](http://github.com/ptarjan/gpg-encrypt/tree/master): "It simply decrypts the file into a file readable only by you, you edit it in your favorite editor, and then it rencrypts 
it and saves the file back where it came from."

The Vim help (`:help :X`) says about the algorithm:

> - The algorithm used is breakable.  A 4 character key in about one hour, a 6
>     character key in one day (on a Pentium 133 PC).  This requires that you know
>     some text that must appear in the file.  An expert can break it for any key.
>     When the text has been decrypted, this also means that the key can be
>     revealed, and other files encrypted with the same key can be decrypted.
> - Pkzip uses the same encryption, and US Govt has no objection to its export.
>     Pkzip's public file APPNOTE.TXT describes this algorithm in detail.

Comment: Note that Vim now has new, more secure algorithms, the default being blowfish2. The note quoted here applies only with `set cryptmethod=zip`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide anything from the root user, even in memory (they have access to /dev/mem). That's a fact that can't be avoided.

So I'd just use temp files in your home directory which should be protected from everyone except root. On one line, enter:

```
echo "testing" >~/proc$$ ; vim ~/proc$$ ;
    grep "good" ~/proc$$ ; rm -f ~/proc$$
```

If you want real security, move the file to a box where you are the only root user and do it there. Then move the encrypted file back.

Comment: Is using mktemp and working out of that file just as good? Here is my script : http://github.com/ptarjan/gpg-encrypt/tree/master

Comment: Probably (I've never used mktemp), but the file is not just readable by you. The root user can do *anything*. The only solution is to not have the unencrypted file anywhere except on a box you totally trust (and that includes "in memory").

Comment: Yeah, sadly I'm just adding more hurdles to steal the file and will never be fully secure. Good point though.