# Is there a java based implementation of the shred/wipe found in linux

Tags: java

i have a file that I need to permanently delete without any traces of it in memory kind of similar to Linux wipe/ shred commands. is there a way for me to use java inbuilt function for this without using any Linux shell calls.
currently I'm using the below code

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("shred -zu -n 5 " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: I don't think so. See this (old) related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6240266/2513200

Comment: yup looks like i will have to stick with this approach. anyways thanks.

Comment: The dup also explains *why* there isn't a Java solution for this.