# GnuPG - How to edit the file without decrypt and save to local disk first?

Tags: linux, encryption, gnupg

I'm using GNUPG to encrypt my ascii files.

I learnt to generate a key, also how to use the it to encrypt and decrypt a file.

There are two ways I used:

```
gpg -d foo.txt.gpg
```

and

```
gpg --output foo.txt --decrypt
foo.txt.gpg
```

I realized the first method will display the decrypted file on the screen, for example when I executed the command over SSH.

With regard to the second method, I concerned if it will leave a trace on the local pc - the 
foo.txt file.

Most importantly, I don't know how to edit the contents of the foo file on the fly.
Ideally, I would like to open the file over SSH use nano/pico, type my passphrase to decrypt, then edit the file, save it and encrypt it. I very much like to avoid save any files to the local disk.

Any comments are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

One way is using `vim`. See [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Edit_gpg_encrypted_files) and this [related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908457/how-can-i-keep-a-file-in-memory-during-editing)

If you need more flexibility or don't want to use `vim`, writing a short program to read the decrypted text coming from STDOUT, edit to your liking, and then re-encrypt isn't too difficult. For example, you could use [this minimal Python code](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxHowtoSmallEditor) (104 lines!) to give you the bare bones editor, and then add the stream reading and writing functionality yourself.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to bear in mind is that holding unencrypted data in memory is no guarantee that it wont find its way to disk.  If the system in question is under heavy load any unencrypted data may be written to the swap partition.  Similarly, if the system is put into sleep mode, the state of any suspended processes will be stored to disk.  If your program is running on a embedded system, it's conceivable that your memory and "disk" are one and the same.

The `mlock()` system call will protect allocated memory from getting swapped to disk.  However, this requires administrative privileges and limits you to a low-level language where you are directly responsible for memory management.

That said, it is prudent to avoid creating files with unencrypted data.  Just know that this doesn't offer you 100% safety if the underlying system is compromised.

Comment: Another (better?) solution to having sensitive data swapped to disk is to encrypt your swap partition.  Once that is done, you no longer have to worry about what is getting swapped.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a python script to solve this (for Linux only). It works by decrypting the file into /dev/shm to ensure that the unencrypted data is never written to disk (although it is possible for any of the programs using the data to be swapped to disk; this is almost always a concern).

This has some benefits over some of the other posted answers:

- Only need to type the password once
- Works with any editor

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, subprocess, getpass, stat, shutil

editor = 'nano'
dataFile = sys.argv[1]

## make a backup of the encrypted file
bakFile = dataFile+'-gpgedit_backup'
shutil.copy(dataFile, bakFile)
dstat = os.stat(dataFile)

##  create temporary directory in tmpfs to work from
tmpDir = '/dev/shm/gpgedit'
n = 0
while True:
    try:
        os.mkdir(tmpDir+str(n))
        break
    except OSError as err:
        if err.errno != 17:  ## file already exists
            raise
    n += 1
tmpDir += str(n)

os.chmod(tmpDir, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR)


try:
    ## Get password
    passwd = getpass.getpass()

    ## decrypt file
    tmpFile = os.path.join(tmpDir, 'data')
    cmd = "gpg -d --passphrase-fd 0 --output %s %s" % (tmpFile, dataFile)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.stdin.write(passwd)
    proc.stdin.close()
    if proc.wait() != 0:
        raise Exception("Error decrypting file.")

    ## record stats of tmp file
    stat = os.stat(tmpFile)

    ## invoke editor
    os.system('%s %s' % (editor, tmpFile))

    ## see whether data has changed
    stat2 = os.stat(tmpFile)
    if stat.st_mtime == stat2.st_mtime and stat.st_size == stat2.st_size:
        raise Exception("Data unchanged; not writing encrypted file.")

    ## re-encrypt, write back to original file
    cmd = "gpg --yes --symmetric --passphrase-fd 0 --output %s %s" % (dataFile, tmpFile)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.stdin.write(passwd)
    proc.stdin.close()
    if proc.wait() != 0:
        raise Exception("Error encrypting file.")
except:
    ## If there was an error AND the data file was modified, restore the backup.
    dstat2 = os.stat(dataFile)
    if dstat.st_mtime != dstat2.st_mtime or dstat.st_size != dstat2.st_size:
        print "Error occurred, restored encrypted file from backup."
        shutil.copy(bakFile, dataFile)
    raise
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(tmpDir)
    os.remove(bakFile)
```

Comment: This does not encrypt it in the way it before originally.

Answer (score 2):

Where is [gnupg plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=661) - exactly for this point for example

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to have a [tmp filesystem in ram using tmpfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59305/458741) then when you power off it's gone for ever.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Luke's answer, I wrote a Python script myself. Hopefully, somebody will find this useful. Here are the core features:

- uses temporary file under /dev/shm using a secure method to generate tempfile
- creates backup file in case of failures
- both encryption modes (public key/symmetric)
- create a new file on-the-fly
- choose your editor through environment variables

Further information can be found in the script itself. It currently won't work on any non *nix-machine.

To install the script just put it in any directory on your path and make it executable.

[Get it now!](https://gist.github.com/a-ludi/641d5e3ca0bb9c1d8bd1)

*Warning: Backup your data! The script comes without any warranty!*

Answer (score 1):

I have spent countless hours on this quest, too: simply encrypt a text file with a passphrase with simple open+read/write access.  I didn't want to deal with private/public keys nor keyrings bound to an OS login, blah, blah, blah.  File encryption with passphrase only is so simple and so universal and perfect for a simple text file to hold passwords.  No bloat nor complication of a database-driven solution like KeePass, etc. (which also requires data entry into multiple GUI elements rather than just typing your passwords in a searchable text file).  The gold standard on Windows is Steganos LockNote.  How to do it on Linux?  Surprisingly very difficult to find, but...

I finally converged on the recommendation I consider best: cream.  http://cream.sourceforge.net/  Cream is a facade to vim to make it more-user-friendly ... useful for other family members (I am a Linux geek at work comfortable with vi[m], but I needed something more accessible for my family).

Just enter:

"vim -x yourfile.txt"

It will be saved as encrypted with a passphrase.

You can use vim or cream at this point:

"vim yourfile.txt" or "cream yourfile.txt".

Either one will natively open "yourfile.txt" and prompt for the passphrase and transparently allow edits and re-saving as encrypted.  FINALLY the quest has been completed !!!!

Comment: This works in git bash on Windows, without installing Cream. @user5429938 What kind of encryption does `vim -x` use?

Answer (score 0):

If your editor can read input from a pipe, and save to a pipe, then you can actually use the version of gpg that decrypts to stdout and encrypts from stdin. Unfortunately, for nano, reading from a pipe is only [planned for 2.4](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/TODO). E.g. for gvim, you can [bind decryption and encryption (through pipes) to a key](https://www.antagonism.org/privacy/gpg-vi.shtml).

Comment: Hi, my browser suggested the last link is "The site's security certificate is not trusted!"

Comment: So just trust the site yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To open gpg files, editing them and then ecrypt/save again use:
kgpg
icon in systray has option: Editor...
Press on it, then open the gpg file, then on the bottom there is a button to decrypt it and voila you have your file in the editor, after you made any changes just press Encrypt and then save it.

Answer (score 0):

Just today I have found out about a way of doing all that in vim!

here is the link: [full howto on setting up vim for gpg files](http://www.tolaris.com/2010/09/27/editing-gpg-encrypted-files-in-vim/)

works like a charm, just in that tutorial, the link to the plugin is url to a page so not to wget it, but go to the page and select the one you want to download.

Answer (score 0):

I detest vi, so i had to make up some glue around nano. This is what i came up with. Downside is that you have to enter password again when encrypting.

`alias file_ed="gpg file.txt.gpg; nano file.txt; gpg -c --force-mdc -o file.txt.gpg_temp file.txt; mv file.txt.gpg_temp file.txt.gpg; rm file.txt"`

It isn't very secure from the filesystem point of view, but I fear other users and myself, not root.

Answer (score 0):

[viencrypt](https://github.com/ptarjan/viencrypt) by Paul Tarjan is a script for editing GPG encrypted files on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the editor joe ( aka [Joe's Own Editor](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/) ) in a command similar to

`gpg --decrypt foo.txt.gpg | joe - | gpg --armor --recipient name@example.com --encrypt > bar.txt.gpg`

will do what you're looking for.

The `-` in `joe -` tells joe to take its input from stdin and to write its output to stdout when you save the file (hit **ctrl**+**k** and then **x** to save). Joe will initially display some crufty output from gpg; this can be cleared by hitting **ctrl**+**r** to refresh the screen.

I use `> bar.txt.gpg` to specify the output file instead of `--output bar.txt.gpg` because the `--output` flag causes gpg to open an interactive dialogue if you're overwriting the output file, and this confuses joe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight improvement to @Luke's answer.   It makes two small improvements:

- It avoids the stack trace if the file is unmodified during the edit session.
- It restores the original gpg file if re-encryption back to the original gpg file was attempted, which is a little safer than checking the modification dates of the edit file.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

# Downloaded from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510105/gnupg-how-to-edit-the-file-without-decrypt-and-save-to-local-disk-first/12289967#12289967
# and then slightly improved.

import os, sys, subprocess, getpass, stat, shutil

editor = 'nano'
dataFile = sys.argv[1]

## make a backup of the encrypted file
bakFile = dataFile+'-gpgedit_backup'
shutil.copy(dataFile, bakFile)
dstat = os.stat(dataFile)

##  create temporary directory in tmpfs to work from
tmpDir = '/dev/shm/gpgedit'
n = 0
while True:
    try:
        os.mkdir(tmpDir+str(n))
        break
    except OSError as err:
        if err.errno != 17:  ## file already exists
            raise
    n += 1
tmpDir += str(n)

os.chmod(tmpDir, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR)


reEncrypted = False
try:
    ## Get password
    passwd = getpass.getpass()

    ## decrypt file
    tmpFile = os.path.join(tmpDir, 'data')
    cmd = "gpg -d --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase-fd 0 --output %s %s" % (tmpFile, dataFile)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.stdin.write(passwd)
    proc.stdin.close()
    if proc.wait() != 0:
        raise Exception("Error decrypting file.")

    ## record stats of tmp file
    stat = os.stat(tmpFile)

    ## invoke editor
    os.system('%s %s' % (editor, tmpFile))

    ## see whether data has changed
    stat2 = os.stat(tmpFile)
    if stat.st_mtime == stat2.st_mtime and stat.st_size == stat2.st_size:
        print "Data unchanged; not re-writing encrypted file."
    else:
        ## re-encrypt, write back to original file
    reEncrypted = True
        cmd = "gpg --yes --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase-fd 0 --output %s %s" % (dataFile, tmpFile)
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        proc.stdin.write(passwd)
        proc.stdin.close()
        if proc.wait() != 0:
            raise Exception("Error encrypting file.")
except:
    ## If there was an error AND re-encryption was attempted, restore the backup.
    if reEncrypted:
        print "Error occurred; restoring encrypted file from backup."
        shutil.copy(bakFile, dataFile)
    raise
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(tmpDir)
    os.remove(bakFile)
```

I would have posted these suggested improvements as comments to @Luke's answer -- which I like a lot -- but did not have enough reputation points to do so.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a shell script to edit files encrypted with gpg.
Call it like `./editgpg.sh  path/to/.secrets.gpg`, edit with vim then close with ':q!'.
Vim flag '-n' opens file only in memory. No temp files.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash


# decrypt CRYPT_FILE, pipe to vim, and encrypt againg whent type ':q!'
edit_crypt_file() {
        echo "Enter your gpg encrypted file passphrase,
edit it with vim, then close the editor with ':q!'."

        # first argument is a file encrypted with gpg
        CRYPT_FILE=$1
        # get password user input
        local pass
        read -sp "Password:" pass

        gpg_flags='--batch --yes'
        vim_flags='- -n -u NONE --not-a-term'

        # vim command to run before exit with ':q!'
        vim_autocmd=":autocmd VimLeave * :%! tee | gpg $gpg_flags --passphrase $pass -o $CRYPT_FILE -c"

        gpg $gpg_flags --passphrase $pass -d $CRYPT_FILE | vim $vim_flags -c "$vim_autocmd"

        # restart agent in order to lose kept password
        gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
        unset pass
}

edit_crypt_file $1
```